# problems with Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, Request.GraphUserCallback()) function

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm following the tutorial for login on an Android application using facebook.

I've had many problems with the hash keys and everything and I think I've solve them all, because my session already gets the `OPENED` state.

The problem I'm having now is that after I log in facebook, when the session is already opened, the code executes the `Request.executeMeRquestAsync()` and it never enters the `onComplete()` part... any idea?

Here is the code...

```
package com.example.firstandroidapp;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
          try {
                PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.firstandroidapp",
                                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.i("Digest: ", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), 0));
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Test", e.getMessage());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e("Test", e.getMessage());
            }

          if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              // it never gets here...
                  if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

}
```

Thanx very much in advance.
David.

Comment: post the code which you are using so we can help.

Comment: The code is the same that appears in the tutorial... I'll reedit the question... thanx

Comment: see this example : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/ , as I can see you missed lots of things from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

The tutorial tells us to modify AndroidManifest.xml. In the modification I put the tags below in wrong places (I didn't use Eclipse to modify the manifest file) and that prevented the callback.

```
<manifest ...>
  ...
  <application ...>
    ...
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    ...
  </application>
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Try double-check your AndroidManifest.xml. [The official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`Session.openActiveSession` returns the session directly if it is already opened. This might be your problem. The callback might not be called in that case. (Still in the process of implementing this myself.)

Create an instance of the SessionCallback before calling it and - if the session is returned directly - call it:

```
StatusCallback cb = new StatusCallback() {/* implement */};
Session fbSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, cb);
if (fbSession != null) {
    cb.call(fbSession, fbSession.getState(), null);
}
```

Check for the session state inside the callback so you don't have to handle the different states twice.